# Outlook 2013/2016 successfully send e-mail, but it is not delivered

Tags: outlook, outlook-2013, outlook-2016

In my firm there are 5 PCs' Windows 10 updated and with Outlook 2013/2016 updated that successfully send e-mail (that is what Outlook shows), but they are not delivered to addresses that are not in their domain (See Example1). But it works as aspected in one PC, although it has the same network and e-mail configuration as the others. The e-mail is successfully sent if I use the brownser version of the email.

Exemple1: our e-mail domain is X, we successfuly send an email to an email in the domain X, but if we try to sendo to domain gmail.com it is not delivered, although Outlook says it was sent successfuly.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read [tour] and [ask].  Your question is wrong for this site but they can help you at either [su] or [sf] .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted and created again the e-mail account on Outlook, then it worked. Let's hope it doesn't happen again. I'll not post as finished because I'll test for a month and if it still works I'll finish this post.

Comment: So the solution above didn't work. But I discovered that the problem was a link to our webpage that was inserted in the e-mail signature image. What a annoying bug... So, the solution was to remove the web link in all e-mail signatures and it went back to work. Yet, let's test for another month before any conclusions are made.